# Minimum distance to a closed hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be an inner product space and $f$ a continuous linear map on $X$. Define $H_0 = \left\lbrace y \in X, f(y)=0\right\rbrace$.

We want to show that, $\forall x \in X$, $$\text{dist} (x, H_0)= \frac{\left|f(x) \right| }{\|f\|^*}, $$ where $\|f\|^* = \sup \left\lbrace \|f(z)\|, z \in X, \|z\| \leq 1 \right\rbrace $.

I have tried to do this by contradiction, i.e. assuming that $\exists y \in H_0$ such that $d(x, y) <\frac{\left|f(x) \right| }{\|f\|^*}$ but that did not lead me anywhere.

Any hint is much welcomed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your title "hyperplace" shouldn't be "hyperplane" ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I corrected it!

Comment: Regarding your immediate jump to a proof by contradiction, please read this quote by H. L. Royden: https://ergodicity.net/2006/01/26/contradiction-injunction/

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you written down and examined the definition of distance between a point and a set?  This is an excellent place to start for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quote, it's very insightful!

Comment: I have tried
$$
d(x, H_0) = \inf_{y: f(y)=0} d(x,y)
$$
which led me to
$$
d(x, H_0) \leq \inf_{y: f(y)=0} (||x|| + ||y||) = ||x||
$$
but I am not sure how this is useful

Comment: Have a look at "the case of Hilbert spaces" in http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/distance-between-a-point-and-a-hyperplane-not-reached/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $f \neq 0$. One way is easy. $|f(x)|=|f(x-y)| \leq \|f\|^{*} \|x-y\|$ for all $y \in H_0$ so we get $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|^{*} d(x,H_0)$ (by taking infimum over $y$).

For the other part let $0<\epsilon <\|f\|^{*} $ and choose $u$ such that $\|u\|=1$ and $|f(u)| >\|f\|^{*}-\epsilon$. Let $a=\frac {f(x)} {f(u)}$. Let $y=x-au$. Then $f(y)=0$ so $y \in H_0$. Hence $d(x,H_0) \leq \|x-y\|=|a|\|u\|=|a|=|\frac {f(x)} {f(u)}|<\frac {|f(x)|} {\|f\|^{*} -\epsilon}$. Le $\epsilon \to 0$ to finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is super clear